# How to change default alias name in Yii 1.1?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have joined with two table by using model association. This two tables are `films` and `movie_streams` But there is some error

My Query:

```
$film = Film::model()->with('movie_streams')->find(array('select' => '*', 'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id, 'params' => array(':user_id' => $user_id)));
```

Film.php model:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
              'movie_streams' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MovieStream','movie_id'),              
    );
}
```

Error Message:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

I saw by default taking alias name. For `films` table `t` and for `movie_streams` table `t0`

How to set manual alias what I want for my above two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the collision of tables aliases by specifying the alias property of the relation.

```
$comments = Comment::model()->with(array(
     'author',
     'post',
     'post.author' => array('alias' => 'p_author'))
   )->findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> model_name.feild_name

```
$film = Film::model()->with('movie_streams')->find(array('select' => '*', 'condition' => 'film.user_id=:user_id, 'params' => array(':user_id' => $user_id)));
```

or

avoid collision of table by using allias

```
$comments=Comment::model()->with(array(
 'author',
  'post',
  'post.author'=>array('alias'=>'p_author')))->findAll(array(
   'order'=>'author.name, p_author.name, post.title'
 ));
```

,  [more details here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#disambiguating-column-names)